# Pass InputStream through JNA to C code as a File Pointer

Tags: java, c, file-io, jna

I've got a DLL written in C (that I can't edit) that has some function prototype that looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(FILE *bar);
```

I'd like to create a JNA interface to the DLL and it's unclear what I need to pass for the FILE *bar argument.  I assume I need to pass an InputStream (which is my preference), but the JNA literature seems sparse on the subject.

What would the Java interface look like? and what do I really need to pass to foo?

Edit: foo assumes bar is the result of an fopen and calls operations like fscanf.

Edit 2: Ultimately, I have a string in Java that I need to read in C as if it were a file, (which might be a different question altogether).  Ideally I'd like to avoid writing the file, which is why converting an InputStream to a C file pointer is so desirable (and evidently quite difficult).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this - you have no easy way to access the internals of of an `InputStream` instance, and even a `FileInputStream` will most likely not be implemented on top of a stdio FILE *. To see what your Java interface should be like, you'll need to post more about the `foo` function - what it does and how you use it.

If you don't care about what the `FILE *` actually does, you can code up using JNA to call `fopen`, passing in the file name and open mode, and pass the result as an opaque value through to `foo`, e.g. (pseudocode):

```
path = "MyFile.txt";
bar = Libc.fopen(path, "r");
Libfoo.foo(bar);
```

**Update:** If you need to have a string which contains data which you need treated as if it were in a file, I think you are out of luck. Unfortunately, the standard C library is not built on top of a stream abstraction, which means that you are unlikely to be able to achieve what you want unless you can open what looks like a filename but leads to your string data; however, it's going to be much, much easier to bite the bullet and save the string to a temporary file, then open that with `fopen` :-(

Comment: see original question for clarification on foo's functionality -- though I suspect that foo's behavior is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: That's fair, I suppose I'm still not giving you enough information.  Ultimately, I have a string in Java that I need to read as if it were a file in C (which might be a different question altogether).  Ideally I'd like to avoid writing the file.

Answer (score 0):

On POSIX systems, you can do this using a pipe, as long as the string isn't too long (unfortunately "too long" depends on the characteristics of the operating system, but is at least 512 bytes):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int string_to_foo(const char *str, size_t len)
{
    int pipefd[2];
    FILE *infile;

    if (len > PIPE_BUF)
    {
        /* Error - string possibly too long */
        return -1;
    }

    if (pipe(pipefd))
    {
        /* Error - pipe() failed */
        return -1;
    }

    if (write(pipefd[1], str, len) < len)
    {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);

        /* Error - write() failed */
        return -1;
    }

    close(pipefd[1]);

    infile = fdopen(pipefd[0], "r");

    if (!infile)
    {
        close(pipefd[0]);

        /* Error - fdopen() failed */
        return -1;
    }

    foo(infile);

    fclose(infile);

    return 0;
}
```